# Point subdomain to heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns

I have a hostgators shared hosting with domain. In the other side I have node js app on heroku.

Now, is it possible to point subdomain "my_node_app.mysite.com" from my shared hosting to "my_node_app.herokuapp.com"?

Ending result should be when user goes to my_node_app.mysite.com, the node.js app hosted on heroku should be loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to do this add the subdomain to your Heroku app:

`heroku domains:add my_node_app.example.com`

Then in your DNS provider's settings (it will be different for every company), add a CNAME record pointing `my_node_app` to `my_node_app.herokuapp.com.`.

See the [Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) guide on Heroku for more information.